# jQuery nested ul navigation menu, accordion or tree menu?

Tags: jquery, navigation, nested, accordion, jstree

I am unsure of the best option to implement a side navigation menu, that has a maximum of 4 nested UL's. The biggest problem I am having is that some headings that need to expand to show child elements also link to individual pages.

I think the best method is to not link to that individual page by default, instead have an icon next to it which links to that page. The issue I have here is accordions don't seem to like this when Navigating and selecting active items.

I've done some research on jQuery Tree navigation menu's but I am unsure of:
1) how customisable they are,
2) I can have a heading show children and go to an individual page somehow.

What is the best option here for me, please?  Oh and the solution needs to be HTML / CSS / jQuery based only, thank you.

HTML (cut down, there's about 100 links overall):

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu_level_1"><a href="/" >Home</a></li>
  <li class="menu_level_1"><a href="/link2" >Link 2</a></li>
  <li class="menu_level_1">
     <a href="#" >Link 3</a>
     <ul class="sub_menu_2">
        <li class="menu_level_2"><a href="/link4" >Link 4</a></li>
        <li class="menu_level_2"><a href="/link5" >Link 5</a></li>
        <li class="menu_level_2">
          <a href="#" >Link 6</a>
          <a href="/link6" >Go to Link 6</a>
          <ul class="sub_menu_3">
            <li class="menu_level_3"><a href="/link7" >Link 7</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Did you try with the contextmenu (http://www.jstree.com/documentation/contextmenu) plugin of jsTree ? It allows context menu with submenus, you can bind the action corresponding to the clic event, and I think you also can put an image bind the image "onclic" event.

Comment: Thanks Ric, I had a good look into the context menu. My understanding of it is that it allows you to bind events to open that 'right click' menu. As I am using it as a navigation tree, right clicking is not common enough and I don't think, for this task, that menu is the right answer. Please correct me if I understood it wrong though, thanks,

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you provide jsfiddle sample?

Comment: Sure, forgot about jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/bNbBK/ - without any js yet. I want only the 1st level LI's to show onload (as well as the path to the current page). On jsfiddle, 'Link 6' has two links in the LI. 1 for expanding the nested UL, and the other to follow the URL to that single page (this was the main issue I was having with plugins). I was not sure of the best way to implement this, although I think now I will try and write this from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [float/drop](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/basic-float-drop.html) response to oversized content in floats to create the menu, adding an extra `li` for the headings that have both submenus and links to individual pages. Here are a few references:

- [CSSPlay 4-level UL Flyout](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/ul-flyout.html)
- [Simplified Float/Drop Menu](http://thinkhtml.blogspot.com/2009/09/timos-float-drop-css-only-dropdown-menu.html)
- [Original Sitepoint Float/Drop Thread](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?635116-CSS-Test-Your-CSS-Skills-Number-27/page6)